# Wifi Implementation in Qt Using QML

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml, qandroidjniobject

I want to show available wifi networks in listview in QML in Qt creator.

1. I dont want to use B2Qt.Wifi .
2. I have implemented wifi list in android Studio, i want to call that

method from C++ to bind that list to listview in QML Listview.

first java file

```
package com.example.mywifidemo;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.example.myapplication.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView wifiList;
    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    private final int MY_PERMISSIONS_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
    WifiReceiver receiverWifi;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wifiList = findViewById(R.id.wifiList);
        Button buttonScan = findViewById(R.id.scanBtn);
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turning WiFi ON...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
        buttonScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                            MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
                } else {
                    wifiManager.startScan();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver(wifiManager, wifiList);
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, intentFilter);
        getWifi();
    }
    private void getWifi() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "version> = marshmallow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "location turned off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "location turned on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                wifiManager.isWifiEnabled();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "wifi turned on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "scanning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            wifiManager.startScan();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                wifiManager.startScan();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
second java file

package com.example.mywifidemo;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.myapplication.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    WifiManager wifiManager;
    StringBuilder sb;
    ListView wifiDeviceList;
    public WifiReceiver(WifiManager wifiManager, ListView wifiDeviceList) {
        this.wifiManager = wifiManager;
        this.wifiDeviceList = wifiDeviceList;
    }
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            List<ScanResult> wifiList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            ArrayList<String> deviceList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (ScanResult scanResult : wifiList) {
                sb.append("\n").append(scanResult.SSID);
                deviceList.add(scanResult.SSID);
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, sb, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceList.toArray());
            wifiDeviceList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Now on button click in QML i want scan list of wifi like android and show the list in QML listview.

Comment: You'll need to use JNI to call from C++ into Java. More info here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html

Comment: @DavidK.Hess, I am new to qt android developemnet i  can call simple static methods from one class but i am using Broadcastreceiver in android studio how to call that methods in c++ using JNI ?

Comment: The approach I take is to call a static method on the Activity and then have the method on the Activity do anything more complicated than that.